# Is it possible to create a BASH script which will ssh into a remote machine and continue doing things there?

Tags: linux, bash

I've tried doing it myself but after the script logs into the remote machine, the script stops, which is understandable as the remote machine is not aware of the script, but can it be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways:

1. ssh user@remote < script.txt
2. scp script user@remote:/tmp/somescript.sh ; ssh user@remote /tmp/somescript.sh
3. Write an [expect](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) [script](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbash%5D%20expect).

For first 2 options, I would recommend using public/private key pair for logging in, for automation sake.

Answer (score 5):

Try a here-doc

```
ssh user@remote << 'END_OF_COMMANDS'
echo all this will be executed remotely
user=$(whoami)
echo I am $user
pwd
END_OF_COMMANDS
```

When you say "continue doing stuff there", you might mean simple interacting with the remote session, then:

```
expect -c 'spawn ssh user@host; interact'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the remote command at the end of the ssh invocation:

```
$ ssh user@remote somecommand
```

If you need to achieve a series of commands, then it's easier to write a script, copy it to the remote machine (using, e.g. `scp`) and call it as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer perl in such cases:

```
use Net::SSH::Perl;
my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new($host);
$ssh->login($user, $pass);
my($stdout, $stderr, $exit) = $ssh->cmd($cmd);
```

It is less error-prone and gives me better control while capturing stdout, stderr and exit status of the command.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this in your `~/.profile` (or `~/.bash_profile` for instance) should do the trick :

```
function remote {
    ssh -t -t -t user@remote_server "$*'"
}
```

and then call

```
remote somecommandofyours
```

Comment: `"$*'"` ... missing a single-quote? Good luck to all.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by passing a whole function over ssh using *declare -f* to the remote server and then executing it there.  This can actually be done quite simply.  The only caveat is that you have to make sure that any variables used by the function are either defined inside of it or passed in as arguments.  If you function uses any sort of environment variables, aliases, other functions, or any other variables that were defined external to it, it will not function on the remote machine because those definitions will not exist there.

So, here's how I did it:

```
somefunction() {
    host=$1
    user=$2
    echo "I'm running a function remotely on $(hostname) that was sent from $host by $user"
}

ssh $someserver "$(declare -f somefunction);somefunction $(hostname) $(whoami)"
```

Note that if your function *does* use any sort of 'global' variables, these can be substituted in after the declare function by doing pattern substitution with sed or, as I prefer, perl.

```
declare -f somefunction | perl -pe "s/(\\$)global_var/$global_var/g"
```

This will replace any reference to the global_var in the function with the value of the variable.

Cheers!